# VBA Index Match Does not Loop, gives same answer

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I have an Index match Function that I am trying to save as VBA so that I can add it to multiple workbooks. The way I have it coded it keeps giving me the same answer and does not loop to the next cell to find a different keyword. I want it to look at what is in N76 and put answer in O76 which works but for N77 it gives me the same answer as O76, even though the keyword in N77 is different.

Sub Covenant()

```
Dim Covenant_1 As Integer
Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
Dim Covenant_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Cov_Date As Range
Dim Cov_Dates As Range
Dim Cov_Type As Variant
Dim DB_Cov As Variant
Dim Cov_Type2 As Variant




Set Dashboard = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set Covenant_Sheet = Sheets("Covenants")
Set Cov_Date = Dashboard.Range("N74")
Set Cov_Dates = Covenant_Sheet.Range("B4:AB4")
Set Cov_Type = Covenant_Sheet.Range("B6:AB13")
Set DB_Cov = Dashboard.Range("L76:L80")
Set Cov_Type2 = Covenant_Sheet.Range("B6:B13")



For Each Cell In Dashboard.Range("N76:N80")
Cell.Value = Application.Index(Cov_Type, Application.Match(DB_Cov, Cov_Type2, 0), Application.Match(Cov_Date, Cov_Dates, 0))


Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Try this site and use the example as a model: https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/

Comment: I have the correct index/match formula in my excel, I was trying to put it into VBA so I that I can just add the macro to other workbooks rather than having to go through the process of copy/paste formatting etxc.

Comment: Also, make sure your calculations are done in the code. Type `calculate` before `end sub` to make sure your workbooks calculate

Comment: One issue is that you `MATCH()` on `DB_Cov` which is fixed going into your loop.

Comment: How would you make DB_Cov move after each calculation. I.e. for the output that is in O76 I want it based off L76 but for O77 I want L77

Comment: `DB_Cov` is a range of five cells. Which are you trying to match?

Comment: In the Table below you will see what the output table looks like. Right now it calculates the Index Match only off of "Total Leverage, which is correct for the first row but for the next row I want the index match to run off of FCCR. L76=Total Leverage and L77=FCCR                                                                              
 Covenants - Select  Covenent  Current Pass
Total Leverage   3.75   3.15  Y
FCCR                   3.75   1.84  N
Max Capex           3.75   
Min. EBITDA           3.75   
Min. Liquidity           3.75

Comment: Table didnt work....I want row 76 to match off L76 and row 77 to match of L77 ect ect, right now the index match is static and I want it to be dynamic

Comment: `Match` doesn't do that in VBA, you'll have to code the loop yourself.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I explained my question very well, but below is the answer. I needed to add an x variable to run the loop. There have been a few other additions but below should work to run a Index/match loop.

```
Sub Covenant()

Dim Covenant_1 As Integer
Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
Dim Covenant_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Cov_Date As Range
Dim Cov_Dates As Range
Dim Cov_Type As Variant
Dim DB_Cov As Variant
Dim Cov_Type2 As Variant
Dim Cov_Next As Range



Set Dashboard = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set Covenant_Sheet = Sheets("Covenants")
Set Cov_Date = Dashboard.Range("M74")
Set Cov_Dates = Covenant_Sheet.Range("B4:AB4")
Set Cov_Type = Covenant_Sheet.Range("B6:AB13")
Set DB_Cov = Dashboard.Range("K75")
Set Cov_Type2 = Covenant_Sheet.Range("B6:B13")
Set Cov_Next = Dashboard.Range("P74")

For x = 1 To 5
    For y = 1 To 5
Cells(x + 75, 13) = Application.IfError(Application.Index(Cov_Type, Application.Match(DB_Cov.Offset(x, 0), Cov_Type2, 0), Application.Match(Cov_Date, Cov_Dates, 0)), "")

    Cells(y + 75, 16) = Application.IfError(Application.Index(Cov_Type, Application.Match(DB_Cov.Offset(y, 0), Cov_Type2, 0), Application.Match(Cov_Next, Cov_Dates, 0)), "")
    Next y
Next x
End Sub
```